# Create job in sql server agent using view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I have a question If I can populate data to table by executing View in sql server agent using weekly job or is it only possible using stored procedure?

[image: Job_Steps]

[image: Job_Failed]

```
View1: 
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Destinations_1415]

AS

select
sy.styr_student_id,'2014/15' 'Year',q.Surname
,q.Forename,q.Course,pit.prpi_title
,CASE WHEN q.Section = 'BATT' THEN 'BATS' ELSE q.Section collate Latin1_General_CI_AS END AS'Section'
,q.Funding_Type,q.Funding_Body,q.Partner
,c.GNIC_Description 'Outcome',c2.GNIC_Description 'Outcome_Specific'
,q.Completion_Status,sd.stud_mobile_telephone,sd.stud_home_telephone_no
,CASE WHEN sy.STYR_Age_end_Aug < 16 THEN '1416' WHEN sy.STYR_Age_end_Aug < 19 THEN '1618' ELSE '19+' END AgeBand
from sql10.ng.dbo.styrstudentyr sy
Inner join(
SELECT  [Partner Name] 'Partner',[Funding Body] 'Funding_Body'
,[Funding Line] 'Funding_Type', [LearnRefNumber] 'learnerrefnumber'
,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By LearnRefNumber, [funding line] Order By CompStatus) 'row_no'
,[FamilyName] 'Surname',[GivenNames] 'Forename',[Full Name]
,[ProvSpecDelMon_A] 'Course',[ProvSpecDelMon_B] 'Section',[LearnAimRef] 'Learning_Aim'
,[LearnAimRefTitle] 'Learning_Aim_Title',[FundModel] 'Fundmodel'
,[CompStatus] 'Completion_Status'
FROM [CollegeReporting].[dbo].[PFR_1415_tbl]
where [Funding Line] not like '%appre%'
union all
SELECT  [Partner Name] 'Partner',[Funding Body] 'Funding_Body'
,[Funding Line] 'Funding_Type',[LearnRefNumber] 'learnerrefnumber'
,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By LearnRefNumber, [funding line] Order By CompStatus) 'row_no'
,[FamilyName] 'Surname',[GivenNames] 'Forename',[Full Name]
,[ProvSpecDelMon_A] 'Course',[ProvSpecDelMon_B] 'Section',[LearnAimRef] 'Learning_Aim'
,[LearnAimRefTitle] 'Learning_Aim_Title',[FundModel] 'Fundmodel',[CompStatus] 'Completion_Status'
FROM [CollegeReporting].[dbo].[PFR_1415_tbl]
where [Funding Line]  like '%appre%'
and LearnAimRef = 'ZPROG001')q on q.learnerrefnumber collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = sy.styr_student_id collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and q.row_no = '1'
left join sql10.NG.dbo.STDPOutcome o on o.STDP_Student_ID = sy.styr_student_id and o.STDP_Course_Text = '2014'
left join sql10.ng.dbo.GNICodes c on c.GNIC_Code = STDP_Outcome_Type and c.GNIC_Type = 'OUT'
left join sql10.ng.dbo.GNICodes c2 on c2.GNIC_Code = STDP_Outcome_Code and STDP_Outcome_Type = c2.GNIC_Type
left join sql10.ng.dbo.studstudent sd on sd.stud_student_id = sy.styr_student_id
inner join sql10.ng.dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance pit on pit.prpi_code collate Latin1_General_CI_AS = q.Course collate Latin1_General_CI_AS and pit.prpi_instance = '141501'
where sy.styr_year = '2014'

View 2:

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Destinations_1516]
AS
select
sy.styr_student_id,'2015/16' as 'Year'
,q.Surname,q.Forename,q.Course
,pit.prpi_title,q.Section collate Latin1_General_CI_AS 'Section',q.Funding_Type
,q.Funding_Body,q.Partner,c.GNIC_Description 'Outcome'
,c2.GNIC_Description 'Outcome_Specific',q.Completion_Status
,sd.stud_mobile_telephone,sd.stud_home_telephone_no
, CASE WHEN sy.STYR_Age_end_Aug < 16 THEN '1416' WHEN sy.STYR_Age_end_Aug < 19 THEN '1618' ELSE '19+' END AgeBand
from sql10.ng.dbo.styrstudentyr sy
Inner join(
SELECT  Partner 'Partner'
,[Funding Body] 'Funding_Body',[Funding Line] 'Funding_Type'
,[LearnRefNumber] 'learnerrefnumber'
,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By LearnRefNumber, [funding line] Order By CompStatus) 'row_no'
,[FamilyName] 'Surname',[GivenNames] 'Forename'
,[Full Name],[coursecode] 'Course'
,[section] 'Section',[LearnAimRef] 'Learning_Aim'
,[coursetitle] 'Learning_Aim_Title',[Fund Model] 'Fundmodel'
,[CompStatus] 'Completion_Status'
FROM [CollegeReporting].[dbo].[PFR_1516]
where [Funding Line] not like '%appre%'
union all
SELECT  Partner 'Partner',[Funding Body] 'Funding_Body',[Funding Line] 'Funding_Type'
,[LearnRefNumber] 'learnerrefnumber'
,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By LearnRefNumber, [funding line] Order By CompStatus) 'row_no'
,[FamilyName] 'Surname',[GivenNames] 'Forename'
,[Full Name],[coursecode] 'Course'
,[section] 'Section',[LearnAimRef] 'Learning_Aim'
,[coursetitle] 'Learning_Aim_Title',[Fund Model] 'Fundmodel'
,[CompStatus] 'Completion_Status'
FROM [CollegeReporting].[dbo].[PFR_1516]
where [Funding Line]  like '%appre%'
and LearnAimRef = 'ZPROG001')q on q.learnerrefnumber collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = sy.styr_student_id collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and q.row_no = '1'
left join sql10.NG.dbo.STDPOutcome o on o.STDP_Student_ID = sy.styr_student_id and o.STDP_Course_Text = '2015'
left join sql10.ng.dbo.GNICodes c on c.GNIC_Code = STDP_Outcome_Type and c.GNIC_Type = 'OUT'
left join sql10.ng.dbo.GNICodes c2 on c2.GNIC_Code = STDP_Outcome_Code and STDP_Outcome_Type = c2.GNIC_Type
left join sql10.ng.dbo.studstudent sd on sd.stud_student_id = sy.styr_student_id
inner join sql10.ng.dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance pit on pit.prpi_code collate Latin1_General_CI_AS = q.Course collate Latin1_General_CI_AS and pit.prpi_instance = '151601'
where sy.styr_year = '2015'

View 3 (Union of View 1 and View2 ): 

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Destinations_1415_1516_Union]

AS

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Destinations_1415] 

UNION

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Destinations_1516]
```

Error:

The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "sql10" reported a change in schema version between compile time ("182244063332028") and run time ("182274129276679") for table ""ng"."dbo"."styrstudentyr"".

Please let me know.

Comment: "_executing a view_"?

Comment: Will this query work : INSERT INTO Table
SELECT  * FROM View

Comment: It's 5 seconds to try.

Comment: I tried same query and I get an error: Cound not find stored procedure dbo.View_name. SQLSTATE 42000 Error 2812. The step failed

Comment: I'm afraid your error message is not related to query you posted above. And you are not trying to run a query but trying to execute a job.

Comment: Yes, query runs fine but I want recent data to be populated to the table. So, should I be executing above query everyday? I tried to do this using sql job but unfortunately it fails ...

Comment: You should post real question related to your situation and provide actual information about what, where, how you are doing something and exact error messages you are getting. Of course in case if you want to gain some help here.

Comment: Post jobstep settings screenshot, real query from within it and error message you're receiving - that will be your real question body.

Comment: @IvanStarostin - done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic542765-145-1.aspx

as mentioned - recreate views, recreate synonyms if you have any.

Another thing - if you have `select *` in the view definition - you are guarantied to have issues with this view which will require to recreate this view periodically. For example when underlying view's or table's column list will change - no matter if a column was deleted, added, or changed it's place (column order). I can't remember right now a list of error messages - some of them are alike one you are getting. Something *strange* about compilation and object definitions. Some situations will not cause an exception but will give unexpected results.

One more issue designed in your code - `insert into` without column list specified. You saved one or two minutes and did not write insert column order, did not write select column order but will have to waste much more time trying to identify why everything is going wrong.

Performance question: why is there a `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`? First view returns a constant column value for `year` similarly does second view and these constants are different - so why `UNION`? There are no rows able to be duplicates. `Year` column will always differ.

1. Recreate 1st level views and synonyms
2. Rewrite 2nd level views to avoid `select *` and unnecessary sort+distinct caused by `union`
3. Rewrite insert with column list defined

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I made the changes you suggested and still getting same error :The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "sql10" reported a change in schema version between compile time ("182244062096492") and run time ("182274127729578") for table ""NG"."dbo"."PRPIProvisionInstance"".

Comment: I just used dbcc freeproccache and query is executing fine I will try and see if the job works fine.

Comment: Note, error was not the same - you started with error referencing `styrstudentyr` table, but error you posted above references `PRPIProvisionInstance`.